# SampleDownloaderActivity error

Tags: error-handling, download

I've got a live app on google play store and I'm getting the following error in my sampledownloaderactivity

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.expansion.downloader.SampleDownloaderActivity$2.onClick(SampleDownloaderActivity.java:356)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code at those lines is:

```
 mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mStatePaused) {
                mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
            } else {
                mRemoteService.requestPauseDownload();
            }
            setButtonPausedState(!mStatePaused);
        }
    });
```

When I tried locally to, I can validate the file. I also tried the same code via beta testing (just the sample downloader, not the whole project). All buttons seemed to be working. Tried downloading in the test project over wifi, over cellular and everything looked good.

Any thoughts?